# Raytracing Shadows

Tags: c++, shadow, raytracing, phong

So, I read about raytracing on the net and started writing a Raytracer from scratch in my spare time. I'm using C++, which I've been learning for about a month now. I have read up on the theory of raytracing on the net and so far its working quite well. Its just a basic Raytracer, that uses neither models or textures.

At first it made a Raycaster and was quite pleased with the result.
[image]

So then I tried multiple objects and it worked too. I just used diffuse shading in this implementation and added to the colour of the light to the object colour at the points it is not shaded. 
[image]
Unfortunately this Code did not work for multiple light sources. So then I started to rewrite my code, so that it supports multiple lights.
I also read up on Phong illumination and got to work:
[image]
It even works with multiple lights:
[image]

So far I'm pleased, but now my I'm kinda stuck. I've tried fixing this for quite some time but I came up with nothing. When I add a second Sphere or even a third, only the last Sphere is illuminated. By last I mean the object in my array where I store all objects.See code below.
[image]

Clearly the purple Sphere should have a similar illumination, since their center lie in the same plane. To my surprise the sphere only has the ambient illumination --> shaded, which should not be the case.

So now my trace function:

```
Colour raytrace(const Ray &r, const int &depth)
{
    //first find the nearest intersection of a ray with an object
    //go through all objects an find the one with the lowest parameter

    double t, t_min = INFINITY;
    int index_nearObj = -1;//-1 to know if obj found
    for(int i = 0; i < objSize; i++)
    {
        //skip light src
        if(!dynamic_cast<Light *>(objects[i]))
        {
            t = objects[i]->findParam(r);
            if(t > 0 && t < t_min) //if there is an intersection and
            //its distance is lower than the current min --> new min
            {
                t_min = t;
                index_nearObj = i;
            }
        }
    }
    //now that we have the nearest intersection, calc the intersection point
    //and the normal at that point
    //r.position + t * r.direction

    if(t_min < 0 || t_min == INFINITY) //no intersection --> return background Colour
        return White;
    Vector intersect = r.getOrigin() + r.getDirection()*t;
    Vector normal = objects[index_nearObj]->NormalAtIntersect(intersect);

    //then calculate light ,shading and colour


    Ray shadowRay;
    Ray rRefl;//reflected ray
    bool shadowed;
    double t_light = -1;
    Colour finalColour = White;
    Colour objectColor = objects[index_nearObj]->getColour();
    Colour localColour;
    Vector tmpv;

    //get material properties
    double ka = 0.1; //ambient coefficient
    double kd; //diffuse coefficient
    double ks; //specular coefficient
    Colour ambient = ka * objectColor; //ambient component
    //the minimum Colour the obj has, even if object is not hit by light
    Colour diffuse, specular;
    double brightness;
    int index = -1;
    localColour = ambient;
    //look if the object is in shadow or light
    //do this by casting a ray from the obj and
    // check if there is an intersection with another obj
    for(int i = 0; i < objSize; i++)
    {
        if(dynamic_cast<Light *>(objects[i])) //if object is a light
        {//for each light
            shadowed = false;
            //create Ray to light
            //its origin is the intersection point
            //its direction is the position of the light - intersection
            tmpv = objects[i]->getPosition() - intersect;
            shadowRay = Ray(intersect  + (!tmpv) * BIAS, tmpv);
            //the ray construcor automatically normalizes its direction
            t_light = objects[i]->findParam(shadowRay);



            if(t_light < 0) //no imtersect, which is quite impossible
                continue;

            //then we check if that Ray intersects one object that is not a light
            for(int j = 0; j < objSize; j++)
            {
                if(!dynamic_cast<Light *>(objects[j]))//if obj is not a light
                {
                    //we compute the distance to the object and compare it
                    //to the light distance, for each light seperately
                    //if it is smaller we know the light is behind the object
                    //--> shadowed by this light

                    t = objects[j]->findParam(shadowRay);
                    if(t < 0) // no intersection
                        continue;
                    if(t < t_light) // intersection that creates shadow
                        shadowed = true;
                    else
                    {
                        shadowed = false;
                        index = j;//not using the index now,maybe later
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //we know if intersection is shadowed or not
            if(!shadowed)// if obj is not shadowed
            {
                rRefl = objects[index_nearObj]->calcReflectingRay(shadowRay, intersect); //reflected ray from ligh src, for ks
                kd = maximum(0.0, (normal|shadowRay.getDirection()));
                ks = pow(maximum(0.0, (r.getDirection()|rRefl.getDirection())), objects[index_nearObj]->getMaterial().shininess);
                diffuse = kd * objectColor;// * objects[i]->getColour();
                specular = ks * objects[i]->getColour();//not sure if obj needs specular colour
                brightness = 1 /(1 + t_light * DISTANCE_DEPENDENCY_LIGHT);
                localColour += brightness * (diffuse + specular);
            }
        }
    }
    //handle reflection

    //handle transmission

    //combine colours
    //localcolour+reflectedcolour*refl_coeff + transmittedcolor*transmission coeff

    finalColour = localColour; //+reflcol+ transmcol
    return finalColour;
}
```

Next is the render function:

```
for(uint32_t y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    for(uint32_t x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        //pixel coordinates for the scene, depends on implementation...here camera on z axis
        pixel.X() = ((x+0.5)/w-0.5)*aspectRatio *angle;
        pixel.Y() = (0.5 - (y+0.5)/w)*angle;
        pixel.Z() = look_at.getZ();//-1, cam at 0,0,0

        rTmp = Ray(cam.getOrigin(), pixel - cam.getOrigin());
        cTmp = raytrace(rTmp, depth);//depth == 0
        pic.setPixel(y, x, cTmp);//writes colour of pixel in picture
    }
}
```

So here are my intersect functions:

```
double Sphere::findParam(const Ray &r) const
{
    Vector rorig = r.getOrigin();
    Vector rdir = r.getDirection();
    Vector center = getPosition();
    double det, t0 , t1; // det is the determinant of the quadratic equation: B² - 4AC;

    double a = (rdir|rdir); 
    //one could optimize a away cause rdir is a unit vector
    double b = ((rorig - center)|rdir)*2;
    double c = ((rorig - center)|(rorig - center)) - radius*radius;
    det = b*b - 4*c*a;
    if(det < 0)
        return -1;

    t0 = (-b - sqrt(det))/(2*a);
    if(det == 0)//one ontersection, no need to compute the second param!, is same
        return t0;

    t1 = (-b + sqrt(det))/(2*a);
    //two intersections, if t0 or t1 is neg, the intersection is behind the origin!

    if(t0 < 0 && t1 < 0) return -1;
    else if(t0 > 0 && t1 < 0) return t0;
    else if(t0 < 0 && t1 > 0) return t1;
    if(t0 < t1)
        return t0;
    return t1;
}

Ray Sphere::calcReflectingRay(const Ray &r, const Vector &intersection)const
{
    Vector rdir = r.getDirection();
    Vector normal = NormalAtIntersect(intersection);
    Vector dir = rdir - 2 * (rdir|normal) * normal;
    return Ray(intersection, !dir);
}

//Light intersection(point src)
double Light::findParam(const Ray &r) const
{
    double t;
    Vector rorig = r.getOrigin();
    Vector rdir = r.getDirection();
    t = (rorig - getPosition())|~rdir; //~inverts a Vector
    //if I dont do this, then both spheres are not illuminated-->ambient
    if(t > 0)
        return t;
    return -1;
}
```

Here is the abstract Object class. Each sphere, light, etc. is an object.

```
class Object
{
    Colour color;
    Vector pos;
    //Colour specular;not using right now
    Material_t mat;
public:
    Object();
    Object(const Colour &);
    Object(const Colour &, const Vector &);
    Object(const Colour &, const Vector &, const Material_t &);
    virtual ~Object()=0;

    virtual double findParam(const Ray &) const =0;
    virtual Ray calcReflectingRay(const Ray &, const Vector &)const=0;
    virtual Ray calcRefractingRay(const Ray &, const Vector &)const=0;
    virtual Vector NormalAtIntersect(const Vector &)const=0;

    Colour getColour()const {return color;}
    Colour & colour() {return color;}
    Vector getPosition()const {return pos;}
    Vector & Position() {return pos;}
    Material_t getMaterial()const {return mat;}
    Material_t & material() {return mat;}

    friend bool operator!=(const Object &obj1, const Object &obj2)
    {//compares only references!
        if(&obj1 != &obj2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

I use a global array of Object Pointers to store all lights, spheres, etc of a world:

```
Object *objects[objSize];
```

I know my code is a mess, but if anybody has an idea what is going on, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT 1 I added pictures.

EDIT 2 Updated code, fixed a minor Error. Still no solution.

Update: Added render code, which creates rays.

Comment: My general approach to debugging things like this is to render a single misbehaving pixel (one of the purple ones that shouldn't be in shadow but is), and add a lot of debug output, like which object is the shadow ray hitting.

Comment: By the way, using `operator|` for dot product isn't the best idea, due to it having the wrong precedence and being very unconventional.

Comment: And what is `operator!` in `intersect+ !(objects[i]->getPosition() - intersect)*BIAS`?

Comment: I know, that the operator | is not the best approach for dot product, because it has a very low precedence, but I think that I used braces around each dot product. I chose to use it, because I also use it on paper. As for the ! operator, I use it for normalizing a vector. Since it has higher precedence than the multiplication, there shouldn't be a problem. My guess is that there is something wrong with the intersect function, but I'm not sure. Anyways thanks for the input.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: I checked out your website, especially Dimension and I have to say it looks awesome!!

Comment: When you test for intersections of the shadow ray with geometry, why do you interrupt the internal cycle if (t >= t_light)? For the shading problem, it looks like the N dot L is negative, thus leaving only the ambient factor.

Comment: A very good point. I just tried different versions, to fix my problem, and I think I forgot to change it back. As for N dot L, I just don't get why this works for one object only and not multiple..is there an error I don't see?

Comment: Try to exclude the nearest object (index_nearObj)  when you check if the shadow ray intersects an object (the j index).

Comment: It did not work. I think I already solved that(it gave me random black pixels-->self shadowing) with the line    shadowRay = Ray(intersect  + (!tmpv) * BIAS, tmpv);    . tmpv is the direction of the shadowray and I start a tiny bit above the object(intersect + tmpv * BIAS).

Comment: Because I start away from the object, the parameter is negative and t is set to -1 and then the loop continues.

Comment: I've found the solution to your problem: check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem found

I managed to debug your ray tracer using Linux and gcc.
Regarding the problem, well... once I found it I felt the urge to bash my head repeatedly against my keyboard. :)
Your algorithm is correct, *except* for a little sneaky detail:

```
Vector intersect = r.getOrigin() + r.getDirection()*t;
```

When you calculate the intersection point, you use `t` instead of `t_min`.
The fix consists in changing the above line to:

```
Vector intersect = r.getOrigin() + r.getDirection()*t_min;
```

The correct output is the following:

[image]

## Other suggestions

I think the problem lies in your shadow ray loop:

```
        //then we check if that Ray intersects one object that is not a light
        for(int j = 0; j < objSize; j++)
        {
            if(!dynamic_cast<Light *>(objects[j]))//if obj is not a light
            {
                //we compute the distance to the object and compare it
                //to the light distance, for each light seperately
                //if it is smaller we know the light is behind the object
                //--> shadowed by this light

                t = objects[j]->findParam(shadowRay);
                if(t < 0) // no intersection
                    continue;
                if(t < t_light) // intersection that creates shadow
                    shadowed = true;
                else
                {
                    shadowed = false;
                    index = j;//not using the index now,maybe later
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically, when an intersection is found, you set the `shadowed` flag to `true`, BUT you continue the cycle: this is both inefficient and incorrect.
When an intersection is found, there is no need to search for another.
My guess is that your `shadow` flag is set to false again because you don't stop the loop.
Also, when `t >= t_light` you interrupt the cycle, which is also incorrect (it's just like `t < 0`).
I would change the code to the following:

```
            //then we check if that Ray intersects one object that is not a light
            for (int j = 0; j < objSize; j++)
            {
                // Exclude lights AND the closest object found
                if(j != index_nearObj && !dynamic_cast<Light *>(objects[j]))
                {
                    //we compute the distance to the object and compare it
                    //to the light distance, for each light seperately
                    //if it is smaller we know the light is behind the object
                    //--> shadowed by this light

                    t = objects[j]->findParam(shadowRay);

                    // If the intersection point lies between the object and the light source,
                    // then the object is in shadow!
                    if (t >= 0 && t < t_light)
                    {
                          // Set the flag and stop the cycle
                          shadowed = true;
                          break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Some other suggestions:

- Refactor your rendering code by adding a function which given a ray finds the closest/first intersection with the scene. This avoids code duplication.
- Don't overload operators for dot product and normalization: use instead dedicated functions.
- Try to reduce the scope of your variables as much as possible: this improves code readability.
- Keep exploring raytracing stuff because it's awesome :D

Comment: I like this approach, definitely better than mine, but it still does not solve the multiple objects problem...Maybe my intersection functions are wrong? I don't know...but thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. If you are interested, I could send you the source.

Comment: Upload your project and link it here, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The Matrix.h header is missing! (edit: however, it seems that it's not used :P)

Comment: Yep, I added it just in case I wanted matrices for rotation or translation, which I dont use atm.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Can you post the output you obtain with your pc? Mine is this, which looks _really_ wrong: https://hostr.co/7J4ERkTLELK6

Comment: I'm using gnu gcc 4.8.2 with -std=c++11 enabled in the CodeBlocks IDE. I uploaded the most recent output in the dropbox.

Comment: Unfortunately my compiler produces different results, so it's pointless to debug it.

Comment: What compiler are you using?Anyways thanks for taking a look, I will need to get some sleep now before tomorrow.

Comment: MSVC. However, I'm signin off for the night, maybe I'll try something tomorrow.